# What is HwndSource's deal with non WPF windows?

Tags: wpf, mfc, interop

I've been working with a WPF app that my client wants to host inside of an MFC application. I have that working fine. But I have an interop communication with a third process using windows messages. **When I pass the handle for the main window (an MFC window) to `HwndSource.FromHwnd`, it gives me null.** What is going one here. The documentation doesn't even mention this behavior.

Comment: Use Spy++ to have a look-see.  Good odds that the WPF window is a child window of your MFC window.

Comment: The WPF window is an indirect child of the MFC window. I'm just trying to create an HwndSource with an WPF window and it is giving me NULL.